# Light indication of a 2-bar system while on the correct glideslope?

Tags: vasi

I am trying to compare a VASI-4 light system with a PAPI lights. I know that 2White-2Red is the pattern that indicates that the aircraft is on the glideslope; more reds mean lower and more white means higher than the desired glideslope height. With relations to that, how should the VASI lights be on a correct/incorrect approach?

P.S. My question is specific to VASI-4 light system aka 2-bar VASI.

**UPDATE** I found [this](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim/aim0201.html) from FAA that may very well be the answer, but an explanation would be great.

Comment: @FreeMan        I didn't ask for how they work. I don't see this as a duplicate. I asked for the sources that confirms what the correct indication for 2-bar VASIs should be

Comment: The sources are contained in the answers of the other question.